# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] subfiles

Tags: errors, subfiles

My paper was doing fine when I had all the text and figures in main.tex. However, now that I am using the subfiles package to organise my paper, when compiling main.tex I get the message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].  
\graphicspath #1->\def \Ginput@path 
                                    {#1}
l.73 \subfile{sections/method1}
```

when I compiled method1.tex as a standalone file, it worked.

My main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\parindent 0ex
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
style=numeric, 
sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
 

\section*{Method 1: Geometric approach}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Method 1: Geometric approach}

\subfile{sections/method1}


\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={References}
]


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\graphicspath{\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}}` is certainly wrong. Why are you nesting the graphicspath command?

Comment: I wouldn't particularly recommend subfiles unless you have special requirements (it complicates the processing quite a lot)  but that is unrelated here. `\graphicspath{\graphicspath` is an infinite loop so will fill the stack.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out my mistake! I did not see that. Everything is working out now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a very specific issue of a misused command.